# Volatile fields and locals not being removed

Tags: java, synchronization, volatile, java-memory-model

Consider the following code snippet

```
class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

}

class PersonPrinter {

    private Person person;

    void print() {
        Person p = this.person;
        System.err.println(p.getFirstName());
        System.err.println(p.getLastName());
    }

    void setPeron(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

}
```

Pretend there are concurrent invocations of the methods `setPerson()` and `print` by multiple threads on the same `PersonPrinter` instance.

Because the code is not properly synchronised, the JVM is allowed to introduce optimisations as long as the "*as if serial*" semantics is maintained.

In particular the `print()` method can re-arranged as:

```
    void print() {
        System.err.println(this.person.getFirstName());
        System.err.println(this.person.getLastName());
    }
```

That is removing the local variable in favour of direct access to the field: this will not alter the single thread semantics. Of course such optimisation may cause to print the first name of one person, and the last name of another (as another concurrent thread can invoke `setPerson()`).

I have the feeling that marking the `person` field as volatile in PersonPrinter will solve the issue, and prevent the local from being removed (hence guaranteeing that we print firstName and lastName of the same person).... but I was unable to find the reason why that is the case in the oracle docs: by looking at the rules of the java memory model, what prevents locals from being removed in favour of direct access to a volatile field ?

Comment: Can you provide citations for your reasoning? I don't see any explanation for why eliding a local variable would be permissible, as that is _explicitly_ an operation that creates a "private" copy.

Comment: For what I understand, removing the private copy is (at least theoretically) allowed, as it wouldn't change the single thread semantics of the method: the as "if serial" semantics is maintained, and you wouldn't be able to tell the difference if you were to run the code on a single thread. The opposite (i.e., a local introduction) is also allowed

Comment: But _it does_ change those semantics in exactly the way that you demonstrated. By making a private copy, there's no possible way that anyone else can interfere with the private copy.

Comment: It does not change the semantics *within thread*, that is removing the local and using field access does not change the semantics *within thread*, hence it is allowed: In a multi-threaded environment one must use synchronization to guarantee the thread safety. What I am looking for is the bit of docs stating that setting the field to volatile prevents such optimisations to be allowed. According to your reasoning operations reorder should also be not allowed as it can change the milti-threaded semantics of your code ....

Comment: Sure it does. You're accessing _something different_.

Comment: This is a good presentation on the topic: m.youtube.com/watch?v=ADxUsCkWdbE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Besides the fact that removing a local variable to do redundant reads instead would be a rather unusual "optimization", if you claim that a JVM was allowed to do that, you are the one to prove that, e.g. by providing a source.

Comment: Of course I wouldn't expect such behaviour to be implemented in any jvm (the heap is more expensive to access than the stack) but such behaviour wouldn't change the "as if serial" semantics and as such theoretically legal unless stated otherwise. I was looking for the bit in the docs that would make such behaviour to be illegal. In other words, the opposite behaviour (from field to local) is allowed and perfectly legal unless the field is volatile (that is otherwise it could break the 'happens before' condition on the field). Looking for the reason why this behaviour would be illegal, not inef

Comment: You are repeating this “as if serial” rule, but there is no such rule that was saying that an optimizer can do anything as long as the serial semantics are retained. This “as if serial” serves well as an explanation why failing to use thread safe constructs can cause weird behavior, but it does not work as a formal rule describing what an optimizer is allowed to do. A local variable is per se unshared, so witnessing a sudden change of its value that must have been done by a different thread, in other words a shared behavior, would violate the specification.

Comment: Of course there is, ot is part of language spec: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model

Comment: but you might have convinced me....  the bit of spec defining that might be: §17.4:

Each time the evaluation of thread t generates an inter-thread action, it must match
the inter-thread action a of t that comes next in program order. If a is a read, then
further evaluation of t uses the value seen by a as determined by the memory model

 and §17.4.1
[...]
Local variables [...] are never shared between threads and are unaffected by the memory model.   By doing that transformation they would make the MM affect the local.

Answer (score 1):

> In particular the `print()` method can re-arranged as:
>
> ```java
>     void print() {
>         System.err.println(this.person.getFirstName());
>         System.err.println(this.person.getLastName());
>     }
> ```
>
> ... Of course such optimisation may cause to print the first name of one person, and the last name of another (as another concurrent thread can invoke `setPerson()`).

This new behavior (and therefore this optimization) is illegal because it violates Java Memory Model (JMM).

From [Java Language Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4):

> The memory model describes possible behaviors of a program. An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be predicted by the memory model.

In your original code `this.person` is accessed once in `print()`, so it corresponds to a single `Read` action.

Your optimized version of `print()` reads `this.person` twice and gets different values.
This behavior cannot be explained by the single `Read` action, therefore it violates the JMM.

Answer (score 0):

Reasoning about incorrectly synchronized programs is very hard.

Like your already indicated the code is not correctly synchronized. To be precise: there is a data race on the Printer.person field: there are at least 2 threads that can access this field and at least one of them is a write.

When there is a data race, you get undefined behavior. From that point on it is pretty futile to reason about the behavior.

If you make the Printer.person field volatile the data-race disappears because a happens before relation is introduced between the write and the read of the field (volatile variable rule).

And the way you do it, reading the object in a local variable and then using that object, is a technique I frequently use. So even through the world progresses, you see the world at a stable point in time.

Comment: _When there is a data race, you get undefined behavior. From that point on it is pretty futile to reason about the behavior._ Strictly speaking, in java this behavior is [defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html) (in contrast to [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races)/[C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races) where it is literally undefined). Although, reasoning about java programs with data races is very hard indeed.